# LWJGL 2 Mouse doesnt give out dx/dy when grabbed

Tags: mouse, lwjgl

I currently am making a game with a FPS type interface. `Mouse.setGrabbed(true)` and i'm trying to use that but now `Mouse.getDX()` and `Mouse.getDY()` does not work anymore and return 0. How can I get the values while the mouse is grabbed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the LWJGL 2 documentation, when grab is true, `getX()` and `getY()` will return the delta coordinate values for the mouse.

Source: http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Mouse.html#setGrabbed(boolean)

Comment: I'm not looking for the values from those methods though I am trying to find the result of Mouse.getDX() which is how much the mouse moved.

Comment: Again, when `grabbed` is set to true, `getX()` returns the same value as `getDX()` when not grabbed and `getY()` returns the same value as `getDY()` when not grabbed.  Grabbing sets the position to the middle of the screen on each input poll.